# Mysql: get highest of one and lowest value of another field in one row

Tags: mysql, max, min

I have a (MySQL) table with two date/time fields: `start` and `end` (each of the type `datetime`). I need a query which delivers me the lowest value from `start` and the highest value of `end` for a certain user and a defined date. I finally suceeded with the following query:

```
SELECT job.id, job.user_id, job.start, last.end 
FROM job
    JOIN job AS last 
        ON job.user_id = last.user_id 
            AND DATE( job.start ) = DATE( last.start ) 
            AND last.end = (SELECT max( last2.end) 
                            FROM job AS last2 
                            WHERE last2.user_id = last.user_id 
                                AND DATE( last2.end ) = DATE( last.end ))
WHERE job.user_id = 1 
    AND DATE( job.start ) = '2012-05-28' 
ORDER BY job.start ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Even though it works, it does not 'feel' right. Is there an easier way to do this?
Any help and hints is/are much appreciated. Thanks!

Example data:

```
user_id     start               end
1       2012-05-28 07:13:00     2011-04-26 07:45:00
1       2012-05-28 08:15:00     2011-04-26 08:50:00
1       2012-05-28 05:32:00     2011-04-26 05:51:00
1       2012-05-28 08:50:00     2011-04-26 09:50:00
1       2012-05-28 15:10:00     2011-04-26 15:40:00
1       2012-05-27 16:11:00     2011-04-26 16:46:00
2       2012-05-28 09:50:00     2011-04-26 10:35:00
```

Comment: `DATE( job.start )` ??? What type is the `job.start` column?

Comment: Some sample data and expected outputs would go a long way to help us help you.

Comment: Order by job.start does not return the lowest value from start. It returns all values for given user *starting with* the lowest value from start. If the given user has two rows in job with the same end date, they'll both be returned.

Comment: It return the lowest value if you limit it to one value with LIMIT 0,1

Comment: Is there supposed to be multiple rows for the same user_id? I thought it's meant to show the lowest start and the highest end once, for each user_id

Comment: Is the expected output `{1,2012-05-28 9:50:00,2011-04-26 16:46:00}`?

Comment: The expected output is {1, 2012-5-28 5:32:00 2011-04-26 15:40:00} - user and day are criteria. Sorry, start and end does seem to be logical but it doesn't matter for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select user_id
  , Min( start ) As MinStart
  , Max( end ) As MaxEnd
From job
Where Date( start ) = '2012-05-28'
  And user_id = 1
Group By user_id, Date( start )
```

Based on your comment that `{1, 2012-5-28 5:32:00 2011-04-26 15:40:00}` is the expected output (which is why sample output is so important), that indicates that the start and end date values do not necessarily have to relate to an actual row's value. For example, there is no row with the combination of values in your sample data. Given that, the solution is simpler.

I grouped on `Date( start )` only to show that if you remove the Where clause, you can determine the min and max start dates by start day. Given that you are filtering on both, you can simplify the query to:

```
Select user_id
  , Min( start ) As MinStart
  , Max( end ) As MaxEnd
From job
Where Date( start ) = '2012-05-28'
  And user_id = 1
Group By user_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cc99/51) verison

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT job.user_id,min(job.start) AS orderby,max(job.end)
FROM job
WHERE job.user_id=1
GROUP BY job.user_id
HAVING DATE(job.start)='2012-05-28'
ORDER BY orderby
LIMIT 1
```

Untested, hope it'll work for you, and make a little more sense.

By using aggregate functions we can easily find the min and max, however what I had to take out (or I could include, but would make the query quite a bit more complex) is the job.id. If you need to include it, you'd have to use subqueries to select a job with that user_id and job.start matching the minimum one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it does not seem to work, because the min of start is in one row and the max of end is in another.

Comment: That's weird, that's exactly why I thought it should work. The group by allows us to easily deal with lots of different rows, as long as the user_id is the same. We can then use the aggregate functions min and max to select the ones we want. How exactly isn't it working?

Comment: Well that means the problem is in the HAVING condition. You may have to include the hours:minutes:seconds or change the comparison type.

Comment: It exists a row with start = NULL, which seems to cause the problem. Is there a way to exclude all rows with start = NULL?

Comment: I guess you could add job.start IS NOT NULL in the WHERE clause, although I'm not sure why that'd be a problem

Comment: That also does not seem to work but if you put `DATE(job.start) = '2012-05-28' it works. Weird! Cheers!

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'll update it then. Good to know I could help you :)